# Is there a term for spelling errors that occur when heterographs are mixed up?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, errors

For example: "I am quitting this job with immediate affect."

Comment: Niether "effect" nor "affect" are heterographs. They are not pronounced the same way. They are pronounced the way they are written.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say the term was *misspelling*.